# i want to write a Windows application about inventory check, which software language should I use?

Tags: windows, web-apps, python, software-development, swift

I want to write a program and that program should work in my shop's inventory check and also that program should run in Windows. I have a just 40 items and when i checked, i want to write that check information on application which i want to write.
Which programming language should i use ?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that asking for programming languages is off-topic here. For details, see: [Should programming language recommendations be allowed here?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a small scale use case I would take all the help I can get. In this case probably Excel and Visual Basic (VBA).

I assume that this will be “single user”? To be more precisely “no two people messing with the data at the same time”?

Yes? Then try Excel!

You’ll get (basically for free):

- a “database” very likely more than sufficient for your needs (the work sheets)
- Pivot tables are *awesome* for planning and inventory management
- lots of UI and tools, e.g. coloring items based on some condition (“color all red where stock is depleted “)

If you need more complex features, use VBA macros.

Just one tip: Find a good way to make backups, regularly (at least daily) and religiously (at least weekly check that the backup is restoreable)

Writing and maintaining (!!) a software AND doing what you do to earn money is **very, very risky** because you have a good chance that you will be overwhelmed and fail at both.

Comment: i probably use excel for that problem, that makes much more sense. Thank You.